# jquery 'on' not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-callback

I've a statically created table:

```
<table id="table" style="width:100%">
    <tbody id="tbody">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I've dinamically created some elements:

```
var tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');   

for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.appendChild( createDiv(i,j)); // div id is = i + ' ' + j
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
}
```

But now I'm trying to add a callback function for each div, but this is not working. I think that the problem is with the jquery on function but I don't know how to solve it.

```
for(var x=0;x<8;x++){
    for(var y=0;y<8;y++){
        $(document.body).on('mousedown', '#' + x + ' ' + y, function(){
            var audio = document.getElementById('audio');

            audio.currentTime = 0;
            audio.play(); 
        });
    }
}
```

When I try to do the same with static elements it works fine, does anybody know what is happening? Thanks

Comment: id values cannot contain spaces.

Comment: And can not start with a number

Comment: Thank you for your help, that was the problem! Thanks!

Comment: Are you really using `jQuery`? I see `document.getElementById` and `document.createElement`. The only thing `jQuery` that seems to be there is `.on()` I'd seriously reconsider that personally....

Comment: @ntgCleaner nothing wrong with ID's starting with number, it's perfectly valid

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry, I guess I read this article wrong https://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/

Comment: @ntgCleaner look at date...it's 9 years old. html5 spec allows it

Comment: @charlietfl thank you for updating me: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: @charlietfl: It's valid HTML, but not a valid selector unless the leading number is escaped. jQuery allows it because they're selector engine is non-conforming (IMO, broken) in a number of different ways, including that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other answers here that are correct in their answer, but I wanted to add a bit more clarification.

The purpose of [jQuery's on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is to attach event handlers to selected elements. The purpose of the `selector` parameter is to create a delegated handler. From the jQuery documentation:

> The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that match the selector.

In addition:

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

(I would recommend you read the whole section on *Direct and delegated events* by the way.)

In any case, for your particular example, you want to build your DOM in such a way that there is a top-level element that is guaranteed to exist at the time the delegated event is attached. It may be your table, or a div element above your table. You could also attach to the body or the document, but, it is better to attach the event to the closest element that will be guaranteed to exist per this documentation:

> Attaching many delegated event handlers near the top of the document tree can degrade performance. Each time the event occurs, jQuery must compare all selectors of all attached events of that type to every element in the path from the event target up to the top of the document. For best performance, attach delegated events at a document location as close as possible to the target elements. Avoid excessive use of document or document.body for delegated events on large documents.

In your particular case, it appears that the table is a guaranteed element. Because of that, you can attach to that and delegate the divs that are inside. (Of course, appropriate adjust your selectors to get the correct divs.) Assuming you want all divs to bubble up, then your attachment would be something like this:

```
$('#table').on('mousedown', 'div', function(e) {
  console.log('Do some stuff here.');
});
```

Of course, you'll want to do this inside the [document ready handler](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) to ensure that your elements are present.

Also, be aware that IDs cannot start with a number in the HTML 4 spec. If you are developing HTML 5, however, [IDs can basically be anything](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) as long as they are unique, don't contain any spaces, and are at least a single character.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document.body).on('mousedown', '#tbody td', function(e){
    //TODO::add code here
});
```

Need not bind event to every td dom.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your armada of event handlers.

Use 3 steps to make it 1 handler for all the dom elements:

Make the sequenctial number part of the id, to have them distinguishable.

Then only instantiate  one eventhandler for the body mousedown call. No more for in for loop.

Distinguish via the event object (argument of your event callback), which id was clicked. (i think it was event.target or the alike)

Regarding the  usage of this like pointed out in the comment, it might be generally useful to reference the id of an dom element that refers to a domain object. Thus the explicit id can directly relate to the underlying resource identifier( pk ...).

Comment: If he gave the elements a class, he could just add a handler for that, and jQuery will take care of binding `this` to the target element.

Comment: Yes, absolutely right ;) This is the most intuitive and straightforward way of doing it ! Maybe step by step ^^

Answer (score 1):

Creating a delegate for each #id is overkill

You can directly attach the click event to each ID in the loop or simple create a single delegate event listener.

```
$("#table").on("click", "div", function(e){
   // use div.class to limit delegate
   // split id, pull values from the dom or innerText
   var el = this;
   var id = this.id;
});
```